# Pointer to int == Pointer to char (somewhat)?

Tags: c, pointers, memcpy

In this code given below , i have declared a pointer to int and we all know that memcpy returns a void pointer to destination string , so if ptr is a pointer to int then why **printf("%s",ptr);** is totally valid , ptr is not a pointer to char after all.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
//Compiler version gcc  6.3.0

int main()
{
  char a1[20] ={0} , a2[20] ={0};
  int *ptr;
  fgets(a1,20,stdin);
  fgets(a2,20,stdin);
  ptr = memcpy(a1,a2,strlen(a2)-1);
  printf("%s \n",ptr);
  if(ptr)
  printf("%s",a1);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just because it works doesn't mean it is "valid".  Passing an `int *` with a `%s` format is undefined behavior.  GCC will warn you if you enable `-Wall` which you always should.

Comment: You don't appear to be actually *asking a question* here; please read [ask].

Comment: In practice, the code probably ignores the type mismatch and treats the bytes in memory at address `a1` as if they were a string, which happens to work in this case.  But there is no guarantee that it always will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First consider `ptr = memcpy(a1,a2,strlen(a2)-1);`. `memcpy` is declared as `void *memcpy(void * restrict, const void * restrict, size_t)`, so it accepts the `a1` and `a2` passed to it because pointers to any unqualified object type may be converted to `void *` or to `const void *`. (Pointers to object types qualified with `const` may also converted to `const void *`.) This follows from the rules for function calls in C 2018 6.5.2.2 7 (arguments are converted to the parameter types as if by assignment) and 6.5.16 1 (one operand is a possibly-qualified `void *` and the left has all the qualifiers of the right) and 6.5.16 2 (the right operand is converted to the type of the left).

Then `memcpy` returns a `void *` that is its first argument (after conversion to `void *`), and we attempt to assign this to `ptr`. This satisfies the constraints of the assignment (one of the operands is a `void *`), so it converts the pointer to the type of `ptr`, which is `int *`. This is governed by 6.3.2.3 7:

> A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type. If the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned for the referenced type, the behavior is undefined. Otherwise, when converted back again, the result shall compare equal to the original pointer…

Since `a1` is a `char` array with no alignment requested, it could have any alignment. It might not be suitable for an `int`. If so, then the C standard does not define the behavior of the program, per the above.

If `a1` happens to be suitably aligned for an `int` or the C implementation successfully converts it anyway, we go on to `printf("%s \n",ptr);`.

`printf` is declared as `int printf(const char * restrict, ...)`. For arguments corresponding to `...`, there is no parameter type to convert to. Instead, the *default argument promotions* are performed. These affect integer and `float` arguments but not pointer arguments. So `ptr` is passed to `printf` unchanged, as an `int *`.

For a `%s` conversion, the `printf` rules in 7.21.6.1 8 say “the argument shall be a pointer to the initial element of an array of character type.” While `ptr` is pointing to the same place in memory as the initial element, it is a pointer to an `int`, not a pointer to the initial element. Therefore, it is the wrong type of argument.

7.21.6.1 9 says “… If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.” Therefore, the C standard does not define the behavior of this program.

In many C implementations, pointers are simple addresses in memory, `int *` and `char *` have the same representation, and the compiler will tolerate passing an `int *` for a `%s` conversion. In this case, `printf` receives the address it is expecting and will print the string in `a1`. That is why you observed the result you did. The C standard does not require this behavior. Because `printf` is part of the standard C library, the C standard permits a compiler to treat it specially when it is called with external linkage. The compiler could, hypothetically, treat the argument as having the correct type (even though it does not) and change the `printf` call into a loop that used `ptr` as if it were a `char *`. I am not aware of any compilers that would generate undesired code in this case, but the point is the C standard does not prohibit it.

Answer (score 0):

> why printf("%s",ptr); is totally valid

It isn’t - it *may* work as expected, but it isn’t guaranteed to.  By passing an argument of the wrong type to `printf`, you’ve invoked undefined behavior, which simply means the compiler isn’t required to handle the situation in any particular way.  You may get the expected output, you may get garbage output, you may get a runtime error, you may corrupt the state of your system, you may open a black hole to the other side of the universe.